# Не получается сгруппировать запрос по дате, т.к. часы и минуты отличаются

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count

Необходимо сгруппировать количество тренеров по дням в таблице:

```
CREATE TABLE lesson
( lesson_id number(5) NOT NULL,
  lesson_section_id number(5) NOT NULL,
  lesson_coach_id number(5) NOT NULL,
  lesson_room number(5) NOT NULL,
  lesson_start_date date NOT NULL,
  lesson_end_date date NOT NULL,
  lesson_cost number(5),
  FOREIGN KEY (lesson_section_id) REFERENCES sections(section_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (lesson_coach_id) REFERENCES coachs(coach_id),
  CONSTRAINT lesson_pk PRIMARY KEY (lesson_id)
);
```

Сделал такой запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(LESSON_COACH_ID),lesson_start_date FROM LESSON GROUP BY lesson_start_date;
```

Проблема в том, что в поле lesson_start_date хранится не только дата, но и время начала занятия. То есть, результатом такого запроса может стать:

```
COUNT: 1, LESSON_START_DATE: 16.04.2020 12:00
COUNT: 1, LESSON_START_DATE: 16.04.2020 13:00
COUNT: 1, LESSON_START_DATE: 16.04.2020 14:00
```

Но мне нужно сгруппировать данные именно по дате. Пытался сделать через `select to_char(lesson_start_date,'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual`, как оказалось, в выражении GROUP BY нельзя использовать подзапросы.

Comment: Если есть тип, хранящий только дату, привести к нему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Как усечь дату в *ORACLE* до определенного значения

Делать это с помощью `to_char` можно, но очень не правильно. Есть замечательная функция `TRUNC` - без параметров она как раз округляет до дня.

Большой список функций с описанием (причем и для других БД) можно посмотреть [здесь](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/index.php), полный список конечно в доке *ORACLE*.

2. Что можно использовать в выражении `GROUP BY`

Подзапросы нельзя использовать, но они и не нужны, т.к. можно сразу использовать сами функции как штатные, так и пользовательские.

```
select 
  count(l.lesson_coach_id),
  trunc(l.lesson_start_date) lesson_date
from lesson l
group by trunc(l.lesson_start_date)
```